# How to check if parent object contains child objects properties? Is there any way without converting object to array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to check if the object property is available to another object that returns true if it has. I tried this way, but it gives false. any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
const checked = {0: true, 1: true, 2: true, 3 true, 4: true}
const newChecked = {0: true, 1: true, 2: true, 3: true, 4: true, 5: true, 6: true, 7: true, 8: true, 9: true}

Object.entries(checked).every(e => Object.entries(newChecked).includes(e))
```

Comment: Why do the objects have consecutive "numeric" properties starting at zero? Imho they should be arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to check properties only, you can use `Object.keys` to do this

```js
const checked = { 0: true, 1: true, 2: true, 3: true, 4: true };
const newChecked = {
  0: true,
  1: true,
  2: true,
  3: true,
  4: true,
  5: true,
  6: true,
  7: true,
  8: true,
  9: true,
};

const has = Object.keys(checked).every((key) =>
  Object.keys(newChecked).includes(key)
);

console.log(has);
```

For both key and value check, you can combine the use of `Object.entries` and `Array.prototype.findIndex`

```js
const checked = { 0: true, 1: true, 2: true, 3: true, 4: true };
const newChecked = {
  0: true,
  1: true,
  2: true,
  3: true,
  4: true,
  5: true,
  6: true,
  7: true,
  8: true,
  9: true,
};

const has = Object.entries(checked).every(
  ([keyToFind, valueToFind]) =>
    Object.entries(newChecked).findIndex(
      ([key, value]) => key === keyToFind && value === valueToFind
    ) !== -1
);

console.log(has);
```